# How to prepare a string in java that will eventually passed into SQL for a search

Tags: java, sql-server, string

This is what I am trying to do

The user enters a string. This gets passed into a java program which then run a query against sql server and tries to find the records where this string occurs. The query that eventually runs against the sql server is something like this

```
Select * from users where name like '*userPassedInText*'
```

The problem I have is that if this string has certain characters such as ' the query breaks. I know the ideal way to do this is to use

```
PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement   (myStatement );
```

But for certain reasons I have to pass in a string. Having said that is there any utility in java that prepares a string to be sent to SQL server?

Comment: If youre using the string entered by the user as it is I have to warn you that your system will be Vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Having said that, you can escape the single quotes in the string. Each RDBMS has its own way of doing it. Check the documentation.

Comment: Pre existing app with both java and .net. java passes string to .net. For certain reasons we are avoiding any changes to the .net code. So this string should be modified before being passed into .net api.

Comment: Can't you just use toString() on the PreparedStatement?

Comment: Don't even try to pretend that simply doing something like replacing ' with '' is even close to good enough. You need to parameterize your queries. SQL injection is so easy to prevent but the way you are doing it you are wide open. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question: you simply need to replace all "single quote" characters with TWO single quote characters:

```
String original ="it's a problem when you have a single quote in SQL params"; // String contains a single quote
String escaped = original.replaceAll("'","''"); // replace all single quotes with 2 single quotes
```

But I cry for you not to simply take whatever the user passes in (especially given that your variable has the name userPassedInText!!). I would strongly urge everyone to read this:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

... because if you just take whatever the user types in, then they can type in "some text with single quotes' OR 1==1". And you SQL will return ALL records from your DB table. You definitely want to use preparedStatements. And, as a bonus, you won't have to manually replace single quotes with two single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

i think u could try this way, creating a connection, and giving the query by prepareStatement method:

```
try {
  String url = "jdbc:odbc:databaseName";
  String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
  String user = "guest";
  String password = "guest";
  Class.forName(driver);
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user, password);
  String changeLastName = "UPDATE authors SET lastname = ? WHERE authid = ?";
  PreparedStatement updateLastName = connection.prepareStatement(changeLastName);

  updateLastName.setString(1, "Martin"); // Set lastname placeholder value
  updateLastName.setInt(2, 4); // Set author ID placeholder value

  int rowsUpdated = updateLastName.executeUpdate(); // execute the update
  System.out.println("Rows affected: " + rowsUpdated);
  connection.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
  System.err.println(cnfe);
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
  System.err.println(sqle);
}
```

here original link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/ConnectionprepareStatementStringsql.htm